# 'make all' error when installing Caffe on Ubuntu 20.04 with OpenCV 4.2.0 for Python3: /usr/bin/ld cannot find lpython3.6m or lboost python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, opencv, caffe

I'm following this article to install caffe: https://qengineering.eu/install-caffe-on-ubuntu-18.04-with-opencv-4.2.html
and get this error after running `make all` with `libboost-all-dev` and `libpython3` already installed.

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_python3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython3.6m
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:596: .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

I have a feeling I may need to create a soft link for the files into path or append to my PATH, LIBRARY_PATH, or LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I'm not actually able to locate the libpython.so or libboost files, so I'm not sure how that would be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check the exact version of `python` that `python3` is pointing to and also whether you have `python3.6m`

```
python3 -V 

python3.6m -V
```

Both should return you **`Python 3.6m`**, otherwise find out exact version of python that is installed or version of python you want to use, accordingly change it in [Makefile](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile).

```
# say it's python3.7
PYTHON_LIBRARIES ?= boost_python3 python3.7
```

**Locate libboost:**

```
locate boost | fgrep .so
```

If `libboost-all-dev` is installed, located path will be either `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` or `/usr/lib64/` or `/usr/lib/` or `/usr/local/lib/` or some thing like this.

Then depending upon path you get (say you get `/usr/lib/`), look for exact libboost.so :

```
ls /usr/lib/libboost_python*.so
```

If return list includes `libboost_python3.so`, check whether `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes path to that (path here for ex: `/usr/lib`), otherwise do:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/libboost/
```

You can add it to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/libboost/' >> ~/.bashrc
```

If `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` includes path to **`.so`** for `libboost`, but name is different, say it's libboost_python-py37.so, accordingly change in Makefile.

```
# say it's python3.7
PYTHON_LIBRARIES ?= boost_python-py37 python3.7
```

Then do:

```
make all
```

Comment: This was the solution, thank you! I was using python3.8 instead of 3.6. There's also two lines in Makefile.config to change to the proper python version as well.